# Connect to Elasticsearch from Fargate Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-fargate, opensearch

Our Fargate tasks are allowed to connect to AWS ES / OpenSearch. It's set up with this policy:

```
 {
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Action = "es:ESHttp*",
        Resource = "*"
      }
    ]
  }
```

And from our Symfony (PHP) application it works flawlessly. However I wanted to try it from the command line inside a running task. So I did a "exec" into one running container and did a CURL request. The response is:

```
{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"}
```

It seems I don't fully understand how it works. I expected the request to be successful, because I sent the request from a task, which is allowed to talk to ES. What am I missing?

Comment: What command did you run inside the container? The request has to be signed with the AWS credentials assigned to the task, and whatever command you used didn't sign the request.

Comment: @MarkB you're totally right! I used a plain cURL command. Now I looked deeper into the AWS PHP SDK and actually found the spot where we do the request signing. I just assumed this is some "AWS magic" and works out of the box, just because the task has this policy assigned. Now I know that under the hood the credentials are still needed to sign the request.

Comment: @MarkB a small follow-up question: so I understand that the policy must be there (resource A is allowed to talk to resource B) + the request must be signed nonetheless. Which OSI layers are those two security measures? The signed request seems to be pretty clearly application level (HTTP), but what about the policy? Also application level or is it something below that?

Answer (score 0):

From Opensearch(ES) to ECS Fargate connection,

Need to create private subnets with NAT Gateway to create ECS Service
Bcoz fargate not having any ip to mention in opensearch for connection

Once Private subnet created , create ecs service with that private subnet.
Mention load balancer security group in ecs service security group.
Mention NAT gateway public subnet IP in opensearch,
&

attach the below policy in ECS task role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "es:ESHttpPost",
                "es:ESHttpGet",
                "es:ESHttpDelete",
                "es:ESHttpPut"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:es:<aws-region>:<accoutno>:domain/<opensearchdomainno>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Connection will work smoothly.

Comment: Does the NAT gateway need to be public?